# jquery event to handle clipboard paste (eg using Clippings, clipple extensions)

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have handled user input, cut, copy & paste through mouse & keyboard using

```
$('[aria-labelledby="Directory_Number_Label"]').bind('paste cut keyup', function(){});
```

But this doesnt work when user paste values using extended clipboard plugins like clippings or clipple.

We tried below code but not able to capture the event.

```
$('[aria-labelledby="Directory_Number_Label"]').on("paste", function(e){
    // access the clipboard using the api
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    alert(pastedData);
} );
```

Also

```
document.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste); 
function handlePaste (e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;

    // Stop data actually being pasted into div
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

    // Do whatever with pasteddata
    alert(pastedData);
}
```

Is there a way to capture the extended clipboard event?

Comment: Have you tried the `input` event?

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan. Tried with $('[aria-labelledby="Directory_Number_Label"]').on('propertychange input', function (e) {
It worked!!!!!
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rory McCrossan it is working in chrome. But not able to capture it on firefox.